# Lagrangian with compound elastic pendulum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, spring

Please refer to the attached image (please excuse my poor drawings skills).
Excuse my language etiquette as I am an engineer, and may not be familiar with all the correct terminology.

The system presents two elastic pendulums supported by a rigid bar.
There is going to be a time varying forcing function applied to the model in the horizontal direction.

When developing the Lagrangian for the system, are the following true:

1. The angle Theta will be equal and so will the associated angular accelerations.
2. Assuming that the above is true, the system will then have 3 degrees of freedom and thus three coordinate systems are needed.
3. The stretch in the springs will cause the horizontal bar to change its angle, since the stretch will not be the same in each spring. If one assumes that the forcing function is always parallel to the rigid bar the forcing function can then be broken up into components, this will then be taken into account when developing the loads applied to each degree of freedom.

How does one account for the rigid bar in the system?

No small angle simplifications will be made for this problem. What are the best numerical techniques to implement to attain a solution?

I am currently looking into the ODE45 functions on Matlab, and Newmark's method which I have developed for my own finite element software.

[image]

Comment: They move in a 2D vertical plane or in 3D space?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

you start with the position vector to the mass $m_1$ and $m_2$

$$\vec R_1=\left[ \begin {array}{c} r_{{1}}\sin \left( \varphi _{{1}} \right) 
\\r_{{1}}\cos \left( \varphi _{{1}} \right) 
\end {array} \right] 
\\
\vec R_2=\left[ \begin {array}{c} r_{{2}}\sin \left( \varphi _{{2}} \right) +L
\\ r_{{2}}\cos \left( \varphi _{{2}} \right) 
\end {array} \right] 
$$

the kinetic energy is:

$$T=\frac 12 m_2\,\vec v_1\cdot \vec v_1+\frac 12 m_1\,\vec v_2\cdot \vec v_2$$

with:
$$\vec v_1=\left[ \begin {array}{c} \sin \left( \varphi _{{1}} \right) {\dot r}_
{{1}}+r_{{1}}\cos \left( \varphi _{{1}} \right) \dot\varphi _{{1}}
\\  \cos \left( \varphi _{{1}} \right) {\dot r}_{{1}}
-r_{{1}}\sin \left( \varphi _{{1}} \right) \dot\varphi _{{1}}\end {array}
 \right]
\\
\vec v_2=\left[ \begin {array}{c} \sin \left( \varphi _{{2}} \right) {\dot r}_
{{2}}+r_{{2}}\cos \left( \varphi _{{2}} \right) \dot \varphi _{{2}}
\\ \cos \left( \varphi _{{2}} \right) {\dot r}_{{2}}
-r_{{2}}\sin \left( \varphi _{{2}} \right) \dot\varphi _{{2}}\end {array}
 \right]
$$
and the potential energy is:

$$U=\frac 12 k\,\left(r_1^2+r_2^2\right)+m_2\,g\,(R_1)_y+
m_1\,g\,(R_2)_y$$

additional you have the holonomic constraint equation

$$F_c=(\vec R_1-\vec R_2)\cdot (\vec R_1-\vec R_2)-L^2=0$$

to obtain the equations of motion you can use the Euler Lagrange method with holonomic constrain equation. Notice that the initial conditions must fulfilled the constraint equation $F_c$

Comment: Thanks for your comments. With regards to the position vector I assume I can also add a term for the stretch in the spring, am I correct?

Comment: I am not sure how you want to do it. The spring forces are taking in account through the potential energy